# stringResource() not loading strings of current locale

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

**Update**

In the application class, I am injecting the `ChangeLanguageRepository`  which sets the app language at each app startup by calling the function `changeLanguage`.

```kotlin
class ChangeLanguageRepository @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) {

    fun changeLanguage(languageLocale: String) {
        val locale = Locale(languageLocale)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val config = Configuration()
        config.locale = locale
        context.resources.updateConfiguration(config, context.resources.displayMetrics)
    }
}
```

I have developed an app using Jetpack Compose in which there is an option to change the language of the app. Now, when the language is changed, all the string resources that are loaded using `stringResource()` are not updating for the current locale even when the activity or app is restarted.

One of the screens inside the app is loading strings using the `Context` provided by Dagger Hilt in the Repository as shown below.

```kotlin
class HelplineRepository @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) {

    fun getHelplines(): List<Helpline> {
        val ambulance = Helpline(
            Icons.Rounded.Emergency,
            context.getString(R.string.helpline_text_ambulance),
            context.getString(R.string.helpline_text_ambulance_number)
        )

        val fireStation = Helpline(
            Icons.Rounded.LocalFireDepartment,
            context.getString(R.string.helpline_text_fire_station),
            context.getString(R.string.helpline_text_fire_station_number)
        )

        return listOf(ambulance, fireStation, policeControlRoom, womenHelpLine)
    }
}
```

This screen properly shows the localized strings when the language is changed but the rest of the screens where I use the `stringResource()` inside a composable to load the strings don't update for the current locale.

**Note**: I have already tried restarting both the activity and the app and have also made sure that the locale is being changed when the user changes the language.

I also found a [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167352819) on the issue tracker mentioning a similar problem but couldn't find the solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How and where are you calling the getHelplines() and also how you are using the list returned by the function please add that code as well

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**

**Composable code**

```
@Composable
fun LocalizedGreeting() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        Column {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    changeLanguage(
                        context = context,
                        language = "it",
                    )
                },
            ) {
                Text("Italian")
            }
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    changeLanguage(
                        context = context,
                        language = "en",
                    )
                },
            ) {
                Text("English")
            }
            Text(
                stringResource(
                    id = R.string.localized_greeting,
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

fun changeLanguage(
    context: Context,
    language: String,
) {
    val locale = Locale(language)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val config = Configuration()
    config.locale = locale
    context.resources.updateConfiguration(config, context.resources.displayMetrics)
    context.startActivity(Intent.makeRestartActivityTask((context as Activity).intent?.component))
}
```

**Video**

[image]

The resources remain the same as the old answer given below.

### Note

**After the language is changed, the activity has to be restarted to get the updated strings. If there are multiple activities in the back stack, all of them have to be restarted.**

---

#### Old Answer

(For using the localized strings without changing the locale programmatically)

To use localized string resources,

**Composable code**

```
@Composable
fun LocalizedGreeting() {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        Text(
            stringResource(
                id = R.string.localized_greeting,
            )
        )
    }
}
```

**Default strings**
**res/values/strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="localized_greeting">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

**Italian strings**
**res/values-it/strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="localized_greeting">Ciao!</string>
</resources>
```

[image]

---

jetpackComposeVersion = "1.2.0-beta02"

---

Using localized strings was straightforward.
Probably you were missing something.
Provide the code you are using for further debugging if required.

Comment: I have added the code that is being used to set the changed locale at each startup.